# Problem building KDE software on OSX

Tags: osx, compiling, kde

I'm trying to build Kate on a OSX machine, following this: https://community.kde.org/Guidelines_and_HOWTOs/Build_from_source/Mac

I managed to follow the HOWTO till the end, but when I issue `emerge Kate` I get the following error:

```
emerge warning: dev-util/extra-cmake-modules failed: Could not find package 

for dev-util/extra-cmake-modules as a dependency of kde/gpgmepp
*** Handling package: extra-cmake-modules, action: all ***
*** Action: fetch for frameworks/extra-cmake-modules ***
Cloning into '.'...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname kde: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
emerge warning: while running  cmd: git clone  kde:extra-cmake-modules .
emerge warning: Action: fetch for frameworks/extra-cmake-modules FAILED
*** Emerge all failed: all of frameworks/extra-cmake-modules failed after 0:00:00 ***
emerge error: fatal error: package frameworks/extra-cmake-modules all failed
```

Any idea about what's causing this and how can I solve it?

edit: new error after installing extra-cmake-modules manually and adding the IP address to `/etc/hosts`:

```
*** Action: fetch for frameworks/extra-cmake-modules ***
Cloning into '.'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
emerge warning: while running  cmd: git clone  kde:extra-cmake-modules .
emerge warning: Action: fetch for frameworks/extra-cmake-modules FAILED
*** Emerge all failed: all of frameworks/extra-cmake-modules failed after 0:00:01 ***
emerge error: fatal error: package frameworks/extra-cmake-modules all failed*** Action: fetch for frameworks/extra-cmake-modules ***
Cloning into '.'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
emerge warning: while running  cmd: git clone  kde:extra-cmake-modules .
emerge warning: Action: fetch for frameworks/extra-cmake-modules FAILED
*** Emerge all failed: all of frameworks/extra-cmake-modules failed after 0:00:01 ***
emerge error: fatal error: package frameworks/extra-cmake-modules all failed
```

edit 2: after using the anonymous repo

```
Cloning into '.'...
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@       WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
The ECDSA host key for kde has changed,
and the key for the corresponding IP address 138.68.4.10
is unknown. This could either mean that
DNS SPOOFING is happening or the IP address for the host
and its host key have changed at the same time.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:00FsaU0+NXKMqBhWLLHhWQpCtHpf35m8UCtSNSnvZbQ.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/<name>/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /Users/<name>/.ssh/known_hosts:2
ECDSA host key for kde has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Comment: You need the extra cmake modules that are required for KDE applications, https://inqlude.org/libraries/extra-cmake-modules.html I don't know how to build these on Mac though, only on Linux

Comment: @munir Emerge should automatically get and compile all the required modules from git. extra-cmake-modules is the first dependency, so correctly emerge tries to download it. However the download fails. If I issue `emerge extra-cmake-modules` I get the same result. The problem is about the connection to the repository, I suspect.

Comment: Try using the address `138.68.4.10` in the hosts entry instead, as it is the address for KDE's anonymous repository instead of the private one.

Comment: @JohnLeuenhagen see the edit, I'm not sure about what to put in `known_hosts`

Comment: @domenicocamasta if you don't mind approving all of the hosts you ssh into one more time, you can safely delete `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. You can also just move it out of `~/.ssh` temporarily while you build this software and then move it back. Oh yeah, and we are the ones doing the DNS spoofing, so you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: even deleting `known_hosts` it asks to accept the fingerprint but then: `Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: @JohnLeuenhagen since the bounty will expire in one hour I'll give it to you, thanks for your support.

Comment: @domenicocamasta please take a look at my most recent edit.

Comment: @domenicocamasta have you tried what I proposed?

Comment: @JohnLeuenhagen Nope, I had no access to the osx machine lately, I'll try it asap

Comment: @domenicocamasta any luck? I'd like to know if I helped and if not how I could.

Answer (score 1):

Try manually installing `extra-cmake modules`.

1. `git clone https://github.com/KDE/extra-cmake-modules.git`
2. `cd extra-cmake-modules`
3. `cmake .`
4. `make`
5. `sudo make install`

This assumes you have git, make, and cmake installed.

Edit:
I looked over the output again, and noticed that git was trying to clone from the hostname `kde`. I don't know why this is, but if it is simply trying to clone from KDE's repos, you can temporarily solve this with an entry in `/etc/hosts`. As of today, the IP address of `git.kde.org` is `138.201.41.178`. So try adding the line `138.201.41.178 kde` to your `/etc/hosts`. This may work if git was trying to clone from that specific repo.

Edit 2:

I think I may have cracked it. It seems that you are able to substitute hosts for `git` in your `~/.gitconfig`. This is far superior to using `/etc/hosts` because you can use hostnames and not just IP addresses. Why don't you try to add

```
[url "git://anongit.kde.org/"]
   insteadOf = kde:
[url "ssh://git@git.kde.org/"]
   pushInsteadOf = kde:
```

to your `~/.gitconfig`. Then try to use `emerge` again. I imagine that this one will work because KDE's website said to use these repos.

Comment: manual install works, however when I try to install kate with emerge I get an error similar to the previous, I'm adding it to the question since it is too big for a comment.